# Flux.using is not emiting items

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm trying to create pull-based source of items. For some reason after pushing one item nothing arrives to the consumer. Whole pipeline is stuck. What am I missing ?

```
private static Flux<ByteBuffer> testRun(String path) {
    return Flux.using(() -> {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
        FileChannel channel = in.getChannel();
        return Tuple.of(in, channel);
    }, t -> s -> {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
        try {
            if (t._2.read(bb) > 0)
                s.onNext(bb.rewind());
            else
                s.onComplete();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            s.onError(ex);
        }
    }, t -> {
        try {
            t._1.close();
            t._2.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. `sourceSupplier` of `using` is called only once.

```
private static Flux<ByteBuffer> testRun(String path) {

    return Flux.using(() -> {
        final FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
        final FileChannel channel = in.getChannel();
        return Tuple.of(in, channel);
    }, t -> {
        return Flux.generate(s -> {
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
            try {
                if (t._2.read(bb) > 0)
                    s.next(bb.rewind());
                else
                    s.complete();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                s.error(ex);
            }
        });
    }, t -> {
        try {
            t._1.close();
            t._2.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    });
}
```